# SQL Server - Display EST as PST?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Server is in NY and date column (DateTime) is being filled as EST. How do users in California view this DateTime as the local PST?

I tried:

```
declare @dte DateTime = '20190919 10:01:01'
select @dte EST, @dte At Time Zone 'Pacific Standard Time' As PST
```

And I get

EST

```
2019-09-19 10:01:01.000
```

PST

```
2019-09-19 10:01:01.000 -07:00
```

I am looking for  2019-09-19 07:01:01.000 -07:00

Comment: Ideally, by storing times only as UTC (optionally with the time zone, in a `DATETIMEOFFSET`) and having their clients adjust the time for them, avoiding any problems with daylight savings time and the other vagaries of time zones. If it's local time and you can't do anything about it, `AT TIME ZONE` is your friend from SQL Server 2016 onwards. Prior to that, things get a lot more clumsy if you only have T-SQL to do the adjustment.

Comment: You need to first tell SQL Server what the current time zone actually is (since this information is not part of `DATETIME`), and then it can recalculate. So `AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'`. If you're going to do a lot of this, you may make to want these calculations available in a view. (Be aware that  range searches for such computed times cannot make effective use of indexes, so this should really only be used for display purposes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeroen already said this in his comment, but I'm making the code concrete so you can see what he means.

Take your initial date, that you know the time zone for, but SQL Server doesn't yet, and tell it the time zone explicitly:

```
DECLARE @dte datetime = '20190919 10:01:01';
SELECT
  @dte AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time';
```

That returns a `DATETIMEOFFSET` value:

```
2019-09-19 10:01:01.000 -04:00
```

Next, convert that value to Pacific time by wrapping it in another `AT TIME ZONE`:

```
DECLARE @dte datetime = '20190919 10:01:01';
SELECT
  (@dte AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS datetime;
```

That returns another `DATETIMEOFFSET`:

```
2019-09-19 07:01:01.000 -07:00
```

Last but not least, for your presentation purposes, wrap *that* in a `CAST` so that you only get a `DATETIME` for your end users:

```
DECLARE @dte datetime = '20190919 10:01:01';
SELECT
  CAST((@dte AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS datetime);
```

Results:

```
2019-09-19 07:01:01.000
```

And Bob's your uncle.

Of course, if you want to take the lazy approach, `DATEADD` will get you where you want to be, too:

```
DECLARE @dte datetime = '20190919 10:01:01';
SELECT
  DATEADD(HOUR, -3, @dte);

2019-09-19 07:01:01.000
```